# Self referencing a table in django

Tags: database, django

Can anyone please explain to me what it means to self-reference a table and why we do so. Whats the point of self referencing a table ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please elaborate, and perhaps give usage scenarios.

Comment: @Chris - Seriously, how does this question not make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you imagine an instance where there are gym member in a database. Some of the people are only gym members, while some people are gym members AND coaches.

So if in the database, there is a column for each member's coach's memberId, then the database will self reference itself when you use a memberId that is already in the database as the coach. That is a use of self-referencing.

Comment: If you think so, would you mind accepting my answer or at least upvoting it? It means a difference for us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Self-referencing tables are used in hierarchical relationships.

Example:  Table Persons:

```
PersonID <-------------
Name                  |
Title                 |
SupervisorPersonID-----
```